# How to have y-axis divided by the total lenght of the data in a seaborn histplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram

I have a large dataset and I am trying to plot an histogram in which the y-axis is a fraction between the number of data with a certain value and the total length of the dataset.
This is my current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
df = df[df['columnA'] == 0]
sns.histplot((df['columnB']),  kde=False, label='label', color='b')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 12})
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.show()
```

How can I do that? Is there a parameter for seaborn histplot that helps with it?

Comment: Note that if your columnB is discrete, it is highly recommended to add `sns.histplot(...., discrete=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to show the percentage instead of the actual count, you could do `sns.histplot((df['columnB']),  kde=False, label='label', color='b', stat = 'percent')`

see [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) :

count: show the number of observations in each bin

frequency: show the number of observations divided by the bin width

probability: or proportion: normalize such that bar heights sum to 1

percent: normalize such that bar heights sum to 100

density: normalize such that the total area of the histogram equals 1

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it seems like the 'percent' option has been removed from the stat parameter. When I try using it it gives me: 
```ValueError: `stat` must be one of ['count', 'density', 'probability', 'frequency'], but percent was passed.`
```

Comment: Other way around; `percent` was added in the most recent release.

Comment: You are correct! Just needed to update my packages, thanks!

Comment: in case you cannot update, probability and percent are not that different